# Is it possible to purge an AWS queue using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, queue, amazon-sqs

I was just wondering if there is an ability to purge queues using ansible/ansible scripts. I was looking through the documentation and the only thing I can find is deleting queues. As we are using ansible to scale up/down systems before/after load testing I would prefer to purge queues using ansible also if possible.

Thanks in advance for all the help. I'm always suprised how helpful people are here.

Thanks all.

Comment: What you're asking for is an imperative action, not a `state=present` or `state=absent` situation where ansible shines; you'll have to use `command:` and [`aws sqs purge-queue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/purge-queue.html) and decide if you need your own idempotency guard (that is: running the playbook multiple times will attempt to purge it each time, is that ok?). Or you can create your own module and use boto3 directly, if you prefer that

Comment: Thank you very much, that was quite insightful!

I think I may have a solution to my problem now.